# Perfmon graph not generated

Tags: performance, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, server, test-configration

I am trying to run a sample test to collect server metrics through Jmeter plugin perfmon.

I have an application running in `localhost` and I have perfmon metrics collector and server agent installed and have checked if they are working fine. There are no issues.

My http sampler works fine and generates results too but I do not see anything in the graphs.

My test ramps up 1000 users in 100 seconds, still nothing in graphs. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm first that communication is happening between your server and your machine.

Also please make sure that the perfmon agent is active and running on the server and then try again.

Feel free to refer below detailed steps as well if required:
[How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: @JananiKrishnan If my answer has helped you in solving your problem, can you please mark it as accepted and upvote it as well?